# save div as an Image in folder

Tags: c#

how to save div as an image in same folder 
 i am using c# . in this below code the image is not saving to folder but it is downloading with the name of html.png . please help

```
protected void ExportToImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=HTML.png");
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright you have a couple of steps,

1. Create a byte array called img wich convert from a string
   After that you Write all bytes to you location and send img with it.
   img being the byte array.
2. The you create the img_converter with the needed parameters, more information about the image converter is provied in the bottom of the awnser
   Then you write all bytes to the file and give the bytes array as a parameter.

I think the rest is pretty easy because the functions already tell what they are doeing.

Note in the bytes array you put your html code

```
1.
byte[] img = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\image.bmp", img);

2.
ImageConverter img_converter = new ImageConverter();
byte[] bytes = (byte[])img_converter.ConvertTo(<strong class="highlight">image</strong>, typeof(byte[]));  
File.WriteAllBytes(savefil.FileName, bytes);

3.
var imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("bitmap.bmp");
var image = imageBytes.ToImage();
image.Save("output.bmp");

4.1 from some file:
Image.Save(@"FilePath", ImageFormat.Jpeg);


4.2.
Image bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\\MyFile.bmp");
bitmap.Save("C:\\MyFile2.bmp");  

5. from pictureBox:
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"path + imageName",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[Save image in folder - msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/73cb15de-5bea-4d82-b5ef-821deb09ce44/how-to-save-image-in-folder-in-c-window-application?forum=winforms)

[ImageConverter Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: sorry i cant undersatad it

Comment: I think its prettu clear wat is al does, if not take a look at the provided links